# Rewrite a javascript file url with .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite following url,

```
http://example.com/widgets/search.js?id=qerwtwttw45777
```

as follows,

```
http://example.com/widgets/search/qerwtwttw45777
```

and tried following rule in htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule search/(.*)/$ /widgets/search.js?id=$1
```

but it fails and showing

```
**500 Internal Server Error**
```

Anybody help to solve this problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in `/widgets/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /widgets/

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.js?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the surplus slash `/` at the end of the pattern, the rule looks fine. So, it must be some other problem.

Maybe, `mod_rewrite` isn't active for your website. You could either look into the server's error log, if available or try just

```
RewriteEngine on
```

without anything else.

If it still has the `500 Internal server error`, rewrite is most likely not available.